# Upload .Net Assembly TcmUploadAssembly.exe Error - Root Element not found error

Tags: templating

We are getting root not found error while uploading .Net assembly using `TcmUploadAssembly.exe`.

We tried creating the config file again from cmd console.

We are not able to find that this error is related to code in custom .Net assembly or any configuration issue.

Comment: Can you give the full details of the error you are getting, and are you trying to upload a new assembly TBB, or is it updating an existing one?
Root Element not found seems to indicate it has a problem with a Parameters Schema, are you embedding a Parameters Schema in your Assembly TBB?

Comment: We are trying to extend the DD4T template. We sure are using the parameter schema. Will check if that is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it was problem with the Parameters Schema.

Comment: In that case you can probably best answer your own question with some details, so that it is useful for future reference